# Better way to check resultset from LINQ projection than List.Count?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Is there a better way to check if a LINQ projection query returns results:

```
IList<T> TList = db.Ts.Where(x => x.TId == 1).ToList();  // More canonical way for this?
if (TitleList.Count > 0)
{
   // Result returned non-zero list!
   string s = TList.Name;
}
```

Comment: No need to use .ToList() either, you can use .Count() on the IEnumerable... but yeah, the .Any() would be better if you don't need to handle the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any()`, or perhaps more appropriately to your example, `SingleOrDefault()`.  Note that if you are expecting more than one result and plan to use all of them, then it doesn't really save anything to use `Any()` instead of converting to a List and checking the length.  If you don't plan to use all the results or you're building a larger query that might change how the query is performed then it can be a reasonable alternative.

```
var item = db.Ts.SingleOrDefault( x => x.TId == 1 );
if (item != null)
{
    string s = item.Name;
    ...
}
```

or

```
var query = db.Ts.Where( x => x.Prop == "foo" );
if (query.Any())
{
    var moreComplexQuery = query.Join( db.Xs, t => t.TId, x => x.TId );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great information.  Not to hijack this thread but how could I select where id = 1 or id = 2 using projection?

Comment: `db.Ts.Where( x => x.TId == 1 || x.TId == 2)`  If you need something arbitrarily complex look at using a PredicateBuilder, http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: @Jacquo another alternative is `var ids = new int[] { 1, 2 }; var query = db.Ts.Where( x => ids.Contains( x.TId ) );` for that particular example.  This translates into `... WHERE TId in (1,2)`.